# How to generate tiff thumbnail for dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Dropzone provides the following instructions for generating a custom thumbnail image:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
   if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
      // This is not an image, so Dropzone doesn't create a thumbnail.
      // Set a default thumbnail:
      myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "http://path/to/image");

      // You could of course generate another image yourself here,
      // and set it as a data url.
```

I can now read the binary image data into a my tif_canvas object using:

```
      var reader = new FileReader();   
      reader.onload = function (event) {
         var buffer = event.target.result;
         var tiff = new Tiff({ buffer: buffer });
         var tif_canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
         var width = tiff.width();
         var height = tiff.height();
         console.log(width + "x" + height);
      };

      reader.onerror = function (event) {
          console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
      };

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

   }
});
```

How do I set tif_canvas to the dropzone thumbnail URL in .emit("thumbnail", file, URL) how can I do this?

Comment: Okay I have figured out the first half of my question; I can get the file image data into the tif_canvas object above by using the following: 
                    var reader = new FileReader();   
                    reader.onload = function (event) {
                        var buffer = event.target.result;
                        var tiff = new Tiff({ buffer: buffer });
                        var tif_canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
                    };
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
How do I get dropzone to use tif_canvas as the thumbnail?

Comment: I figured it out:
                        var dataURL = tif_canvas.toDataURL();
                        myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, dataURL);
this gives me my CIELab tiff as a thumbnail image in dropzone form!